# Microsoft App certification process

Tags: windows, uwp

Just wondering if anyone know how long it takes to get an app certified and published by Microsoft at the moment? The dashboard says a few but could be up to 3 days. I am about to pass the 3 day point and my app is still at the certification phase. I have not heard anything from M/S throughout this process.

Comment: Sometimes it takes a week

Comment: presumably if it then gets rejected it could take a week again when resubmitted?

Comment: According to my experience it will take 3 or 4 more days in this case

Answer (score 1):

According to [**The app certification process**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/the-app-certification-process):

> This process usually is completed within a few hours, though in some cases it may take up to three business days.

Thus, if you still cannot receive the certification result after that, you could open a [**support ticket**](http://aka.ms/storesupport) through your developer account so that Dev Center support could review your specific submission status.

Please select **Application** as your Issue Type and submit an incident.